# How to grant truncate permission aerospike

Tags: database, permissions, aerospike

I am using Aerospike 5.6 and I want to grant truncate to a role? is it possible?
can you please share how, I did not find the right privileges besides grant admin

Answer (score 4):

According to https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/configure/security/access-control for Aerospike version 5.6 (5.1 - 5.7) the privilege responsible for truncates is “write” (Starting at 6.0 there is a dedicated privilege for truncates - "truncate").

A role is a set of privileges and a privilege consists of:

1. Permissions (such as truncate).
2. Scope (global, per namespace, per namespace and set).

Try (using asadm):

```
Admin+> manage acl grant role <role-name> priv write
```